# Chat bot platform

Tags: chatbot, watson-conversation

my boss give me the task to creata a chatbot, not made with Telegram or Slack, in which use Watson Conversation service.

More, the chat bot has to be inserted inside a web page, then it has to be embeddable in html as javascript.

Are there anyone who knows other good platforms to performe these tasks?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Such a broad question... Can you narrow it down? Watson can be found on [Bluemix](http://www.ibm.com/cloud-computing/bluemix/). Make it embeddedable is fine, such ensure you have the correct headers.

Comment: I have made a chat bot in Telegram and Slack. The problem is that I need to interface the chatbot in a web site whitin a chat interface. I've also use Chattlio, rocket chat and live chat, but this platform don't support a bot agent, only users agents are supported.

Comment: Conversation is a rest API. So you can use it as your brain of your chat bot on other chat bot frameworks (eg. Messenger).

Comment: I deep dived into the same question and couldn't find an easy and elegant solution. Bluemix still has another project to reduce the complexity of working with the classifier and dialog services. Usability and time to value with bluemix is poor compared to other NLP platforms. Embedding into web is difficult and expensive. It "can" require standing up services including a IBM Sql database that costs $100s.

Comment: Integrating a web chat style copy and paste with the conversation api is do-able of work. The question is why hasn't anyone done this?

Comment: We (https://x2.ai) have a simple web interface for Tess. It's very easy to program yourself, but we'll probably release an API very soon as lots of people are interested. How have you built your chatbot? Is it an engine (AI with states, flows etc) or just data? Re. to make a chatbot... as you can imagine we've had a go at everything. All of the stuff that you can see on the market is just bad IMO, and so we built our own. BTW, Watson Conversation service is stateless (not a real conversation, like most others). I would go on but I'm not sure what question I'm answering now...

Comment: This question is far too broad in scope for this site. In addition, the [help/on-topic] very clearly says *Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Answer (score 1):

After replying in comments and I had another look and realised Microsoft Bot Framework could work with minimal dev investment (in the beginning).

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/support/embed-chat-control2/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I'm using IBM Watson Virtual Agent but thank you again

Answer (score 1):

This little guy is fun. You should give him a try.

http://www.program-o.com/

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you to build more an *assistant* than a simple bot, using a language understanding service tool like Microsoft [LUIS](https://www.luis.ai/), that is part of the Microsoft Cognitive Services.

You can then combine this natural language processing tool with bot SDK like MicroSoft [Botframework](https://dev.botframework.com/) mentioned above, so that you could easily run queries in natural language, parse the response in a dialog in `entities` and `intents`, and provide a response in natural language.

By an example, a parsed dialog response will have something like this `json`

```
{
        "intent": "MusicIntent",
        "score": 0.0006564476,
        "actions": [
            {
                "triggered": false,
                "name": "MusicIntent",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "ArtistName",
                        "required": false,
                        "value": [
                            {
                                "entity": "queen",
                                "type": "ArtistName",
                                "score": 0.9402311
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
      }
```

where you can see that this `MusicIntent` has a entity `queen` of type `ArtistName` that has been recognized by the language understanding system.

that is, using the `BotFramework` like doing

```
var artistName=BotBuilder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, Entity.Type.ArtistName);
```

A good modern bot assistant framework should support at least a `multi-turn dialog mode` that is a dialog where there is an interaction between the two party like

```
>User:Which artist plays Stand By Me?
(intents=SongIntent, songEntity=`Stand By Me`)
>Assistant:The song `Stand by Me` was played by several artists. Do you mean the first recording?
>User:Yes, that one!
(intents=YesIntent)
>Assistant: The first recording was by `Ben E. King` in 1962. Do you want to play it?
>(User)Which is the first album composed by Ben E.King?
(intents=MusicIntent, entity:ArtistName) 
>(Assistant) The first album by Ben E.King was "Double Decker" in 1960.
>(User) Thank you!
(intents=Thankyou)
>(Assistant)
You are welcome!
```

Some bot frameworks use then a `WaterFall model` to handle this kind of language models interactions:

```
self.dialog.on(Intent.Type.MusicIntent,
    [
      // Waterfall step 1
      function (session, args, next)
      {
            // prompts something to the user...
            BotBuilder.Prompts.text(session, msg);
      },
      // waterfall step 2
      function (session, args, next)
      {
             // get the response
             var response=args.response;
             // do something...
             next();//trigger next interaction
      },
      // waterfall step 3 (last)
      function (session, args)
      {
      }
   ]);
```

Other features to consider are:

- support for multi-languages and automatic translations;
- 3rd party services integration (Slack, Messenger, Telegram, Skype, etc);
- rich media (images, audio, video playback, etc);
- security (cryptography);
- cross-platforms sdk;

Answer (score -1):

I've started to do some work in this space using this open source project called Talkify:
https://github.com/manthanhd/talkify

It is a bot framework intended to help orchestrate flow of information between bot providers like Microsoft (Skype), Facebook (Messenger) etc and your backend services.

I'd really like people's input to see if how it can be improved.